How do I uninstall ICQ on Ubuntu 22.04
How do I uninstall ICQ from Ubuntu 22.04?
Please don't respond with "do it with sudo apt purge ", because I don't know what package it belongs to.  The icon is called "ICQ for Linux" and looks like this: 
The question is specifically about ICQ.
I tried dpkg -S, but it was not helpful:
> dpkg -S icq
app-install-data: /usr/share/app-install/desktop/licq-plugin-kde4:kde4__licq.desktop
app-install-data: /usr/share/app-install/desktop/licq-plugin-qt4:licq.desktop
> sudo apt purge licq-plugin-kde4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package licq-plugin-kde4
> dpkg -S 'ICQ for Linux'
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *ICQ for Linux*


Have you tried asking the system for a package clue?   ie. dpkg -S and passing that command the filespec for the file/icon you're interested in??

Tried it, did not help

Your (additional) pasted details make no sense to me; the result from your first dpkg -S command is the package app-install-data but then your subsequent commands refer to files (not packages).   Lines 2 & 3 are in format "package: filename"

Search all . desktop files to find the one containing the string ICQ like this grep ICQ $(sudo find / -iname "*.desktop").

Does this answer your question? Determining info from icon in Ubuntu 22.04

@FedKad - thank you, it was helpful.  Not exactly in this way, but sudo find / -iname "*.desktop" > desktops.txt then examining the file

I found the way to uninstall ICQ.
sudo find / -iname "*.desktop" > desktops.txt

Most of what it found was in /snap/icq-im/71/usr/share
Then I understood it was a snap app and did snap list then snap remove icq-im.
